# Navbar anchor fill div, WordPress menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm building a site with three menu navigations. The second level menu is generated using the WordPress menu like so :

```
<div class="second_menu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'heritage_overview', 'menu_class' => 'second_menu')); ?>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant portion of CSS.

```
.second_menu {
width: 100%;
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 0;
margin: 20px 0;
font-weight: normal;
li {
    padding: .5em 0;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    opacity: 0.55;
    filter: alpha(opacity=55);
    zoom: 1;
    @media (max-width: @screen-xs-min) {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
a {
    color: white;
    width:auto;
    }
```

}

This creates the second level nav that can be found here: http://heritageco.wpengine.com/. I need visitors to be able to click the background div on the second level menu for navigation.

I've tried using some jquery, something like this:

```
jQuery("#menu-item-33").click(function(){
    ("<a href='/heritage-pacific-group/about/'></a>").click(); 
});
```

as well as CSS using "display: block;" but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Does anyone know a relatively simple solution?

Comment: So to be clear, you want the background of the text to be clickable?  You can do it the way that you're thinking by just adding a little padding...  try adding this line to the 'a' css:
padding: 5px 10px;

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now, you're tal king about the outer most nav, not inner.

Comment: Yes I tried doing that but it is not responsive, when you scale the page down the menu breaks.

Comment: What you want here is the a to inherit the width of the bounding element, right?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add padding to the `<a>` tag and make that fill up the space. This means the whole box will be a link.

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLuhx

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 50%; 
  text-align: center;
}



li a {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#link-1 a {
  background: red;
}

#link-2 a {
  background: green; 
} 

#link-1 a:hover {
  background: orange;
}

#link-2 a:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is to have the  tag contain the li element, not the other way around.. . flip that and will have what you want.  You might need to add a little css to account for the change in styling. But this way the entire li will be clickable, and responsive.

```
<a href="http://heritageco.wpengine.com/heritage-pacific-group/">
  <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34">Heritage Pacific Group
  </li>
</a>
```

alternatively, if you want to keep the same structure: just add this to your css:

```
.second_menu li a {
display:block;
}
```

you want this specificity as display block will break your other a tags inside li elements.

Comment: So this code is being generated using the WordPress menu function.
<div class="second_menu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'heritage_overview', 'menu_class' => 'second_menu')); ?>
</div>
 
Any idea how to have WordPress spit out the menu like you suggested?

Comment: Not that familiar with WordPress...sorry.  Did you try adding the css above?